# Regex in bash shell command works alone, not as part of larger regex

Tags: regex, bash

I've got a short script to move apache log files that are older than x days to a storage location. The regex is capturing the jk.shm.some_number file name in the mod_jk directory, which is an undesired behavior (not a huge issue as I use the mtime flag with a few days cushion to avoid accidental hosing of current active files. Probably the reason I haven't seen this issue pop up so far). The whole regex is:`'[error,access,error_log,access_log,mod_jk.log]*.[0-9]*'` Which I think has only been working due to dumb luck. I've also tried isolating the mod_jk part to run by itself `'mod_jk.log.[0-9]*'` and it works as expected (with or without the \ in front of the .). As soon as i include it inside the brackets, it picks up the jk.shm.some_number file - I'm guessing because it matches a character range in the brackets. I'm trying to work this out using RegexBuddy, but I thought one of the smart folks out there might be able to point out my mistakes and help get me on the right path.

This is the current line that 'works' with the -mtime flag removed:

```
find -name '[error,access,error_log,access_log,mod_jk.log]*.[0-9]*' -type f
```

Comment: Best would be you provide some lines that should be matched.

Comment: error.11111111111, access.11111111, error_log.1111111111, access_log.1111111, mod_jk.log.111111111. Basically the log file filenames in the apache log file directory and subdirectories, which I thought i'd explained above.

Comment: My guess is you are not using a regex at all, but a glob pattern. If you are trying something like `mv {access,error,access_log,error_log,mod_jk.log}.[0-9]* dir` then that is an extended glob pattern, not a regex, and those should be curly braces.

Comment: @tripleee I think you and Chris are getting me closer, I did notice the [] issue when i started breaking this problem down.

Comment: Please post the command or code where you are trying to get this working, you are making us guess hard.

Comment: @tripleee I added the 'offending' line above in the problem statement.

Comment: Yeah, so it's neither. `find` does not support extended patterns or regex in the `-name` option.

Comment: @tripleee I'm reading up on it now and just saw that. I think I'm getting closer using the find -regex flag. If you post an answer along these lines, I'll accept it. Thanks for walking me through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `find` has the `-regex` option, you can use that; otherwise, you will have to split this into individual glob patterns.

```
find -type f -name 'error.[0-9]*' -o -name 'access.[0-9]*' -o -name 'error_log.[0-9]*' -o -name 'access_log.[0-9]*' -o -name 'mod_jk.log.[0-9]*'
```

Note that in glob patterns, `*` is just a DOS-style wildcard, not a regex repetition operator. If you have `find -regex`, you have more control over matching.

```
find -type f -regex '.*\(\(error\|access\)\(_log\)?\|mod_jk\.log\)\.[0-9]+'
```

In both regex and glob `[ab|cd]` only matches one character out of the set enumerated inside the brackets; the pipe character just represents itself in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The `*`s match zero or more characters, so really this regex will match any *.* file name. It seems you'll want to change your`*`s to `+`s, which force at least one match of the previous expression.

Comment: I thought in this case, the [elements]* should match any of the elements within the brackets, not act as a wildcard. The [0-9]* should match any number following the file extension separator'.'. If i use +, nothing gets matched.

Answer (score 0):

I think you ment

```
(error|access|error_log|access_log|mod_jk.log).[0-9]+
```

Your regex matched all names containing only letters in your first square brackets and ",", and maybe some digits after the dot. Only a dot would've been fine, too.

If you want to give alternatives, use round brackets with a pipe as delemiter. Do you know how many digits you have (at least) after the dot?

Comment: For me it works: `TEST=access_log.1111111; EXPR="(error|access|error_log|access_log|mod_jk.log).[0-9]+"; [ $TEST =~ $EXPR ]; echo $?` - How do you execute the regex? I think this expression uses "extended" notation, grep would need some additional flag if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I'm using it as part of a find: find -name 'regex_here' -type f -mtime... I don't know the exact length of each extention, but the [0-9]* seems to be working for now as far as that part of the search goes.

Answer (score 0):

your pattern:

```
'[error,access,error_log,access_log,mod_jk.log]*.[0-9]*'
```

is not doing what you think it is. Even as a regexp it would be flawed, but bash uses globbing.
[] matches one character of kind, but not complete words like you are trying,
* matches non or more occurences of any character, but non a sequence of characters in the range from 0 to 9 as i suppose you are trying to match.

First enable extended globbing with:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

then use:

```
+(pattern1|pattern2|..) for alternate patterns.
```

and

```
+([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|..)
```

HTH Chris

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you got me started down the right path. The issue was that I was using find and not using the -regex option. I appreciate the help.